# How to Stop a currently executing thread

Tags: iphone, ios4, nsthread

Scenario is like this--

In my app there is an Scroll View with many instances of

MyCustomImageDownloaderController(containing imageViews where images are to be assigned after downloading) .

As per our requirement, an image has to be downloaded as we move on to a page.

Scroll View + (MyCustomImageDownloaderController1,               MyCustomImageDownloaderController2, MyCustomImageDownloaderController3.... etc)

Let's say i am scrolling on it,
i reached to page 1 --> image for it should start downloading
i reached to page 2 --> image for it should start downloading...so on

**and if i am on page 3 and images for previous pages if not been dowloaded, they should stop downloading.**

So i tried it with using threads..
on API..

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)sender{

    Step 1) calculated currentPageNumber

    Step 2) started thread for downloading image with url for this currentPage
    //startBackGroundThreadForPlaceImage:(NSURL *) url

    Step 3)stopped thread for previous page , if that is still running

   }
```

Now My MyCustomImageDownloaderController is as

```
-(void) startBackGroundThreadForPlaceImage:(NSURL *) url{

if(isImageDownloaded == NO){

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    //[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadImageInBackground:)       withObject:imageUrl];
    myThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(loadImageInBackground:) object:imageUrl]; 
    //[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadImageInBackground:) toTarget:self withObject:imageUrl];
    [myThread start]; 
    NSLog(@"The current thread is %@ ", [[NSThread currentThread] name]);
    [pool release]; 
}
```

}

NOW Here selector does the work of loading image and assigning to image view

Now Stopping the thread

```
-(void) stopBackgroundThread{
[myThread cancel];

//[[NSThread currentThread] cancel];

//if([[NSThread currentThread] isCancelled]) {
    //[NSThread exit];
//}
    [NSThread exit];
```

}

```
-(BOOL) isThreadRunning{
return [myThread isExecuting];
```

}

So i tried a lot of things, but could not Stop the thread in between..

Basically once instantiated thread using any of three methods

**1) perform Selector in BackGround**

**2) NSThread detach new thread**

**3) NSThread alloc..init with..**

In first 2 methods how to get the instance of the newly created thread, so that i could stoop it,

**as NSThread currentThread doest not give that**

in Method 3,

```
myThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(loadImageInBackground:) object:imageUrl];
```

when i tried

```
[myThread cancel];
```

It did not cancel that thread,,

When i tried

```
[NSThread exit];
```

it hangs on current screen,,,,i guess it has stopped the main thread

Please help me

Thanks in Advance**strong text**

Answer (score 3):

It's generally better to *ask* the thread to stop, rather than forcing it, which should be considered a last resort.  You should, therefore, frequently check a 'stop flag' and when this gets set, terminate the current thread (by simply exiting the method, in this case).  You just need to provide a property on the class the thread is operating on so callers can ask the thread to stop.

It's no different in C++ or Java.

Comment: so basically i need to execute thread inside a loop checking for that flag...if flag changes exiting method will do the job...But can u elaborate it, how will thread perform my task as well as checking for loop...please help me..

Thanks!!!